# Function argument- what it means def train(summary=False):

Tags: python, function, keras, deep-learning

I am using some prelimniary python code and trying to understand it which is based on keras framework for deep convolutional network. There is one line that I can not understand:

```
def train(summary=False):
    path='./result/'
    nb_epoch = 400
    batchsize = 6
    . . . 
    . . .
```

As we can see, train is function but it is taking argument (summary=False). What this is for? 
PS: I am new in Python.

Comment: What part are you asking about? What a parameter is? What the `=False` part is for?

Comment: `summary` is a parameter, and its default value (if not supplied when the function is called) is `False`. What your function does with that parameter we don't know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It simply defines a default value for the `summary` parameter so you can call the function in two ways:

```
train()
train(True) or train(False)
```

Answer (score 1):

This means that when you call this function, the argument `summary` is optional. If you don't pass it, it will assume the default value given, which is `False`.

Somewhere inside the function, this `summary` argument will be doing something. Probably an `if summary == True: model.summary()`, I guess.

---

Examples:

- `train(True)` - calls the function passing `summary = True`
- `train(False)` - calls the function passing `summary = False`
- `train()` - calls the function with the default `summary`, which is `False`